# Downloading a file from React Native WebView

Tags: react-native

**Background**

I am using a WebView to navigate a user to a specific page where a file is downloaded. I am injecting Javascript to the WebView to simulate a click on the download file link. Once the link is clicked with Javascript, the file is opened on the device.

I am trying to find information for downloading the file to the device instead of having it opened in the WebView.

Originally I built this application in IOS where I was able to download the data as a blob then send it to my server using an API. I would like to simulate the same type of functionality.

**Example**

*// This opens the file in the WebView*

```
  const injectedJavaScript = `var confirmLink = document.querySelector("a[href='/file/download']");
      if(confirmLink) { window.location.href = confirmLink.href; }
      `;
      this.setState({ step: "complete" });
      this.webview.injectJavaScript(injectedJavaScript);
```

**Question**

How can I work with this file without opening it on the phone? Ideally I would like to handle the file as a blob but, I would be just as happy to download the file to the phone's storage and then be able to work with it from there.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I need to download the file to the phone's storage instead of opening it on WebView. This is only happening in IOS.

Comment: @DragonBorn Let me know if you got any solutions please

Comment: Hi @jalilIrfan has been years since I worked on this problem but I added an answer below in hopes it helps you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer -**

Read the file from stream and work with it as base64. You can convert the file as base64 and move it anywhere you want.

**Example -**

This example is me injecting JavaScript to get access to a file on a web server. That file is converted to base64 string. Then I post that file to my API where I convert back to the file on my server. The file then lives on my server.

```
const injectedJavaScript = `
      fetch("https://www.example.com/somepath.do?language=en", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: new Headers({
          Accept:
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
          Connection: "keep-alive",
          Referer:
            "https://www.example.com/somepath.do",
          "User-Agent":
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E8301",
          "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=someFile.txt"
        })
      })
        .then(response => {
          response.body.getReader().read().then(function(result) {
             return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result.value));
         }).then(function(b64) {
             fetch("https://api.example.com/api/v1/endpoint", {
               method: "POST",
               headers: {
                 "Content-Type": "application/json"
               },
               body: JSON.stringify({
               data: b64
               })
             }).then(res => {
               console.log(res);
             }).catch(e => {
               console.log(e);
           });
        });
      });
        `;
```